# Pass the value from a Controller to the view

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I created a form and passed the values for **name** and **picture** from the form. The value is accessed from the Upload controller as follows:

```
  $data = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title', true),
    'name' => $this->input->post('name',true),
    'picture' => $this->file_upload($_FILES['picture'])
);
return $data;
```

I need to pass these values to the view so, I modified the above code as:

```
    class Upload extends CI_Controller
{
    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function input_values(){
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name',true),
        'picture' => $this->file_upload($_FILES['picture'])
    );
$this->load->view('documents', $data);    }
        function add(){
        $data = $this->input_values();
        if($this->input->post('userSubmit')) {
          $this->file_upload(($_FILES['picture']));
            if (!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])) {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/docs/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|docx';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
                $data['picture']=$this->file_upload($_FILES['picture']);
            }
        }

        return $this->db->insert('files', $data);
    }

    //logo image upload
    public function file_upload($file)
    {
        $this->my_upload->upload($file);
        if ($this->my_upload->uploaded == true) {
            $this->my_upload->file_new_name_body = 'file_' . uniqid();
            $this->my_upload->process('./uploads/docs/');
            $image_path = "uploads/docs/" . $this->my_upload->file_dst_name;
            return $image_path;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

But I am able to get only the value of title. Following error occurs for both name and title:

```
Message: Undefined variable: name
```

I have accessed the variables from the view as follows:

```
 <?php var_dump($title)?>
  <?php var_dump($name)?
  <?php var_dump($picture)?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to read/access those values?

Comment: I have just done var_dump for those variables please check my edit

Comment: Please show the whole controller. you've not given us enough to find a resolution from.

Comment: Your question title is pretty misleading.

Comment: Please check my edited code

Comment: @SamratShrestha I hope you aren't also calling the same view from some different controller.

Comment: No, I am not. When I print_r the $data from the controller, I get: array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "mhjkg" ["picture"]=> string(35) "uploads/docs/file_5e3d81d3d3da3.jpg" }

But get an error when trying to print it from the view.

Comment: `$data = $this->input_values();`  You know that you're not actually _returning_ anything from `input_values()`, right?

Comment: Yes is that causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

so, this part is where you get the post data and load view (contain the upload form)

```
public function input_values() {
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name',true),
        'picture' => $this->file_upload($_FILES['picture'])
    );
    $this->load->view('documents', $data);    
}
```

then this part is handle the post request from the upload form:

```
function add() {
        $data = $this->input_values();
        if($this->input->post('userSubmit')) {
          $this->file_upload(($_FILES['picture']));
            if (!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])) {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/docs/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|docx';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
                $data['picture']=$this->file_upload($_FILES['picture']);
            }
        }

        return $this->db->insert('files', $data);
    }
```

and this part is where you upload the file

```
public function file_upload($file)
    {
        $this->my_upload->upload($file);
        if ($this->my_upload->uploaded == true) {
            $this->my_upload->file_new_name_body = 'file_' . uniqid();
            $this->my_upload->process('./uploads/docs/');
            $image_path = "uploads/docs/" . $this->my_upload->file_dst_name;
            return $image_path;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

when you call add() function, it call input_values() function then load views then the next line of codes won't be executed (cmiiw).

so, maybe you want to change with this :

```
public function index() {
   if ($this->input->post()) {
      // then handle the post data and files tobe upload here
      // save the post data to $data, so you will able to display them in view
   } else {
      // set the default data for the form
      // or just an empty array()
      $data = array();
   }

   // if the request was not a post, render view that contain form to upload file
   $this->load->view('nameOfTheView', $data);
}
```